# Is "check to make sure" a tautology?

Tags: meaning, redundancy

When one checks (something), would the purpose not be to ensure/make sure? What other purpose does checking have? Even if this a false assumption/argument (purpose equals definition), are there other ways to prove that "check to make sure" is a tautology?

**Edit:**

@FumbleFingers's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292001/is-check-to-make-sure-a-tautology#comment653598_292001) reminded me of the exact usage I had in mind: e.g. "Check to make sure that there are no errors in this document."

Comment: Yes, 'to make sure' fulfils no semantic purpose. But it's got more than one pragmatic use: (1) As an emphasiser / encouraging device (2) Paradoxically, at the same time, as a hedging device (less stark than 'CHECK!').

Comment: You can "check to make sure that ...", e.g. that your software is properly installed. Without a complement after "make sure", I agree that it's a pleonasm.

Comment: Yes, one could argue that either "check" or "make sure" is redundant, but what of it??  The terminology helps to emphasize that the detail being examined is important and worthy of a little extra care.  Redundancy, in and of itself, is not a bad thing.

Comment: I'm not convinced you *have* to see the usage as completely redundant tautology. In my book, ***to check*** can simply mean ***to perform an inspection, investigate*** - this doesn't inherently imply ***making sure** [that there are no problems]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah, I agree with you on that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - However, in order to "make sure" one would assume that a "check" is required, and hence explicitly saying "check" *is* redundant.  (But, as I said earlier, so what?  There's nothing wrong with redundancy.  Just ask NASA.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three related sentences "check to make sure that X," "check whether X," and "make sure that X" all have different meanings.  The first means to determine whether X, to take action ensuring X if you find that X isn't already the case, and to leave it alone if it is already the case.  The second means just to determine whether X, but it does not require any action, whether or not X is already the case.  The third means to ensure X, which you might be able to do without first determining whether X is already the case.

Yet another variant, "check that X," is nearly the same as "check to make sure that X," but it suggests more strongly the speaker's belief that X is already the case.

Answer (score 1):

The word *check* can mean [many things](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/check), including "stop", "investigate" and "mark" (dictionary.com definitions 1, 4 and 7). In the context of air travel, [*checked baggage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checked_baggage) can even mean luggage that travels in the aircraft's hold.

"Check that bag" could be a request to place the bag into the hold, make sure specific contents are present, or an instruction to look inside the bag for contraband.

So although "check to make sure" is a tautology, the less ambiguous portion is "to make sure". That is, if the phrase were to be shortened, it would be better to leave out "check [to]" than "[to] make sure".

Comment: It also carries the connotation of checking something again, rather than the first time -- if you're "checking to make sure" that your English is good, you think it is, but you're giving it another once-over to be certain.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Which is, of course, redundant.

Comment: @HotLicks Not really. You can check something, then check again to make sure your original check was correct. Unless you mean that the make-sure check is redundant, in which case yes but man I'm confusing myself so I'm gonna lie down before I get a headache

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Checking something again is by definition redundant, if there's no reason to believe it changed since the first check.  But, as I've  said repeatedly, there's nothing wrong with redundancy.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, I was getting confused by the multiple connotations of redundant (unnecessary vs. extra) so I took a nap. Now it's pretty clear.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - The problem is that everyone else does the same.  If a sentence (or larger work) contains redundancies, that is no indication that there is unnecessary text present.  (In fact, I've seen writers write pages of unnecessary text with no obvious redundancies.)  "Redundant" does not mean "unnecessary".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - I agree. One could be 'sure' after only checking once, but there does seem to be the connotation here of checking it after already being (at least) somewhat confident, which one would logically only be after having checked it previously.

Comment: @Lawrence - I generally think that shortening "check to make sure"down to "make sure" connotes the same meaning as the original for many circumstances, and therefore is generally acceptable for those circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The implied action by "make sure" in the example sentence ("Check to make sure that there are no errors in this document.") in my edited question includes actually fixing the errors as opposed to checking and reporting there are/are not errors.

Taken from this angle, it doesn't seem to be a tautology.